# flush function always makes polymer test (for dom-if) pass

Tags: polymer, web-component-tester, polymer-3.x

I am writing tests for polymer-3.x element where I am using `dom-if`. According to the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/tests#test-sets), i used `flush`. But this does not evaluate and directly marks all tests as passed.

#### my-element_test.html

```
<test-fixture id="ChangedPropertyTestFixture">
  <template>
    <display-message login='{"auth": true}'></display-message>
  </template>
</test-fixture>

<script type="module">
  suite('display-message', () => {

    test('setting a property on the element works', () => {
      flush(function() {
        const element = fixture('ChangedPropertyTestFixture');
        assert.equal(element.login.auth, false);   // #1 = should fail
        const elementSpan = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('span');
        assert.equal(elementSpan.innerHTML, 'random text');   // #2 = should fail    
        done();
      });
    });

  });
</script>
```

### my-element.js

```
static get template() {
    return html`
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{login.auth}}"> <br>
        <span>Display message</span>
    </template>
    `;
}
static get properties() {
    return {
      login: {
        type: Object,
        value: function(){ 
          return { auth: false }; 
        }
      }
    };
}
```

### If i remove flush

- `#1` fails as expected.
- `#2` says

  > Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

**How to write test case for dom-if, when the condition gets true?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the done to your container as well:

```
test('setting a property on the element works', (done) => {
      flush(function() {
        const element = fixture('ChangedPropertyTestFixture');
        assert.equal(element.login.auth, false);   // #1 = should fail
        const elementSpan = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('span');
        assert.equal(elementSpan.innerHTML, 'random text');   // #2 = should fail    
        done();
     });
});
```